# F5 Big-IP and WSS WebSockets

Tags: ssl, f5-big-ip, socket, wss

We have a F5 Big-IP load balancer that handles the SSL, so the servers behind it get HTTPS rather than HTTP ([SSL off loading](http://www.f5.com/glossary/ssl-offloading/)). I don't have version handy, but in the login page I can see "Copyright 1996-2010", so I guess it is not latest version :)

How will that schema work with WS and WSS? Will the WSS handshake hit the load balancer, and then be forwarded as WS handshake to the web server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On a version of F5 BigIP that old, you will need to do some tricks, as you can't use an HTTP profile and thus not use any fancy F5 HTTP tricks. As of version 11.4 you can use an HTTP profile and still have working websockets. For more info I'd refer you to [this article on the F5 knowledge base](http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/14000/700/sol14754.html) and the articles it links to.

Comment: But that link does not say anything about SSL off-loading and WSS